# How to hide index in Pandas dataframe to JSON function DataFrame.to_json() using 'columns' orientation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eg. My results are returned in this format

```
    "name": {
      "1": "bill",
      "2": "mike",
      "3": "dave"
    },
    "age": {
      "1": 20,
      "2": 21,
      "3": 40
    },
```

but I would prefer the following format

```
    "name": [
     "bill",
      "mike",
      "dave"
    ],
    "age": [
      20,
      21,
      40
    ],
```

Comment: if you are exporting the dataframe to `JSON` ?  if yes then give `index=False` while exporting

Comment: I've tried that but 'index=False' is only valid when 'orient' is 'split' or 'table'

Comment: Use `to_dict()` with `orient='list'` then convert dict to JSON with double quotes.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pandas function [`DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) has an option `orient='list'` that outputs the layout you want.

The only difference is that it outputs a dict with single quote instead of JSON with double quotes.  You can further convert the dict to JSON, e.g. as follows:

```
class dict2JSON(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)

result =  dict2JSON(df.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

**Demo**

```
data = {'name': {1: 'bill', 2: 'mike', 3: 'dave'}, 'age': {1: 20, 2: 21, 3: 40}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.to_json(orient='columns'))

# Old Output 
{"name":{"1":"bill","2":"mike","3":"dave"},"age":{"1":20,"2":21,"3":40}}


# Run new codes:
class dict2JSON(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)

result =  dict2JSON(df.to_dict(orient='list')) 

print(result)

# New Output
{"name": ["bill", "mike", "dave"], "age": [20, 21, 40]}
```